# How enhance the performance of query among several tables?

Tags: sql, performance, informix

Is there some thing should i modify concerning the following query (because it takes long time about `15 seconds` !! just to bring about `400` records)

---

```
 select unique a.regnum  , a.name 
 from re23mmf a , rj82std b , gg7crs c  , rr099stdusr  j , hkcourse  h  , aalt:mms3f x  , aalt:rhcasestudy y 
 where a.regnum = b.regnum and a.regnum = c.regnum 
 and b.term_no = ( select max(d.term_no)   from rj82std d where d.regnum = a.regnum )
 and b.dep_code = j.dep_code and b.study_code = j.study_code 
 and j.start_date <=today and j.end_date >=today  
 and j.emp_num =4324
 and c.crsnum = h.crsnum 
 and h.is_project = 'j' 
 and a.regnum = x.regnum and x.regserial = y.regserial 
 and y.batch_no = ( select max(z.batch_no) from rhcasestudy z where z.regserial = y.regserial )
 and y.case_code <> 5
```

---

And please what should i take care about when writing query like this,concerning the performance issues ?

Comment: Does Informix support INNER JOIN?

Comment: Did you execute `set explain on;` before the select and check the output `sqexplain.out` ?  If your IFX is version >= 11.50 , there you can identify easily where is the bottleneck. Other thing... sub-queries with aggregate function never are good... some cases is much better create a temporary table before and include into the join.

Comment: @ceinmart: Could u write the query agins with the recommended enhancements

Comment: @just_name , before start changing the query, create the explain and analyse it will be more accurate to get this solved. Modifying the sub-queries maybe do not solve if the problem is indexes missing, for example. If you can, create the explain file and edit your question with the content of it. Then we will have more probability to get this solved or will be shots in the dark. Details about the explain command, [read here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v115/index.jsp?tab=search&searchWord=set+explain).

Comment: @ceinmart :I try to put `set explain on;` before my query and run in the `sql editor` i get the result set as usual .
Could  u help me to do that please ?
How could i find the `explain output`,this's the first time i try something like that.

Comment: Hi @just_name , sorry for not being detailed before. The set explain will create the file sqexplain.out on server where the database is, at homedir of the user which is running the query. You will need access to file system of this server or ask your DBA or OS Admin to copy the file to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using JOIN notation, you can write:

```
SELECT UNIQUE a.regnum, a.name 
  FROM re23mmf a
  JOIN rj82std b          ON a.regnum = b.regnum 
  JOIN gg7crs c           ON a.regnum = c.regnum 
  JOIN rr099stdusr j      ON b.dep_code = j.dep_code
                         AND b.study_code = j.study_code 
  JOIN hkcourse h         ON c.crsnum = h.crsnum
  JOIN aalt:mms3f x       ON a.regnum = x.regnum
  JOIN aalt:rhcasestudy y ON x.regserial = y.regserial 
 WHERE b.term_no = (SELECT MAX(d.term_no) FROM rj82std d
                     WHERE d.regnum = a.regnum)
   AND j.start_date <= TODAY AND j.end_date >= TODAY 
   AND j.emp_num = 4324
   AND h.is_project = 'j' 
   AND y.batch_no = (SELECT MAX(z.batch_no) FROM rhcasestudy z
                      WHERE z.regserial = y.regserial)
   AND y.case_code <> 5
```

Unless I goofed during transcription and editing, this is effectively the same as the original query.  I've left the single-table filter conditions in the WHERE clause; the optimizer should push them down to the relevant tables so as to minimize the workload.

As already noted, the key is to study the output from SET EXPLAIN and ensure there are no missing indexes.  It's also a good idea to make sure that statistics are up to date, perhaps using AUS (Auto-Update Statistics).

It would help to identify the cardinalities of the tables.  Generating 400 rows in 15 seconds might be ghastly performance (there are at most 400 rows in any table), or it might be stellar performance (the biggest table has 4 billion rows, each of 2 KiB).  Without sizing information, it is hard to know which is more probable.

```
a ----> b ----> j
|       |
|       +-----> d
|
+-----> c ----> h
|
+-----> x ----> y ----> z
```

The diagram shows the joining structures.  Alias `a` joins to `b`, `c`, and `x` independently; `b` joins to `j` and to (a sub-query on) `d`; `c` joins with `h`; `x` joins with `y`; and `y` joins to (a sub-query on) `z`.

Note that the sub-queries are both correlated sub-queries; those are less efficient, in general.  Maybe you need to use sub-queries like:

```
SELECT d.regnum, MAX(d.term_no) AS max_term_no
  FROM rj82std AS d
 GROUP BY d.regnum
```

in the FROM clause:

```
SELECT UNIQUE a.regnum, a.name 
  FROM re23mmf a
  JOIN rj82std b          ON a.regnum = b.regnum 
  JOIN gg7crs c           ON a.regnum = c.regnum 
  JOIN rr099stdusr j      ON b.dep_code = j.dep_code
                         AND b.study_code = j.study_code 
  JOIN hkcourse h         ON c.crsnum = h.crsnum
  JOIN aalt:mms3f x       ON a.regnum = x.regnum
  JOIN aalt:rhcasestudy y ON x.regserial = y.regserial
  JOIN (SELECT d.regnum, MAX(d.term_no) AS max_term_no
          FROM rj82std AS d
         GROUP BY d.regnum
       ) AS d1            ON b.regnum = d1.regnum AND b.term_no = d1.max_term_no
  JOIN (SELECT z.regserial, MAX(z.batch_no) AS max_batch_no
          FROM rhcasestudy z
         GROUP BY z.regserial
       ) AS z1            ON y.regserial = z1.regserial
                         AND y.batch_no = z1.max_batch_no
 WHERE j.start_date <= TODAY AND j.end_date >= TODAY 
   AND j.emp_num = 4324
   AND h.is_project = 'j' 
   AND y.case_code <> 5
```

These sub-queries only need to be evaluated once, not for each row as in a correlated sub-query. This isn't a guaranteed win, but it often helps a lot.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ,but i find that the enhancements don't change the performance !,nearly the same time .
I don't know what's the meaning of `SET EXPLAIN` and how  i could do it?

I try to put `set explain on;` before my query and run in the `sql editor` i get the result set as usual .
Could  u help me to do that please ?

Comment: SET EXPLAIN is an SQL statement in Informix; SET EXPLAIN ON.  Then run the SQL.  Then find the file `sqexplain.out` and study it.  It explains how the query is executed.  You're looking for things in there that slow it down - non-index access except perhaps on the main table (alias `a`), etc.  Without that, you're running blind.  Without the knowledge of the sizes of the tables, and which indexes are present, and what their schemas are, you're running blind.

Answer (score 3):

First check indexes. Do you have clustered indexes or non-clustered indexes on the tables? You can create a non-clustered index with the columns in your query to improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

1. Put indexes on all joined columns and columns that used by functions that requires sorting (max,min and etc.). It might be several such columns for a single table. In this case try to use their combinations.
2. Use PDQ each time you do sort(unique, order by, group by and etc) or huge join. By the default Informix session memory is too low.
3. Update statistics to high for each indexed in step (1) columns.
4. Use dirty read if applicable.
5. Use execution plan. Check the join order and index usage in different scenarios.
6. Drop unused indexes created in step 1.
7. Consider to review your data model: normalization level decrease. If you expect the result in short time - the number of joined tables has to be 1 in ideal situation. 
   And now..
   Informix optimizer isn't ideal and might to do mistakes especially in such cases. Make sure that execution plan generated is correct and adjust him if required.